# Is it possible to bind select options changes to function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to detect any change in select options and bind it to the function. So far, I am using DOMSubtreeModified event to detect this change but it's not showing proper count if option is deleted from the select.

```
$('#employee').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  alert($('#employee option').size());
});
```

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified [is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified), as is `.size()`

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` is also not well-supported in the first place. Is the code that changes the `<select>` element's content under your control?

Comment: @Frédéric, Control that handle #employee is not under my control. Is there any way to provide listener to options modification event?

Comment: @MrOBrian Is there any other alternative to DOMSubtreeModified? Instead of .size() I can use length.

Comment: @Firoz, alas, not in a portable way, except through polling with a timer. If you're interested in a polling solution, there is probably an answer here that deals with that. I'll have a look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any resolution so I go ahead with the Javascript timer. It's a hack but works for us.